# How to identify the power series I need to use?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Let $$ f(z) = \frac{1}{(z - 4)(z + 8i)} $$

a) Find the domains where f(z) is valid

b) Find its power series at such domains

---

Considering three singularities, I believe the domains are:

$$ D_{1} = |z| < 4 \\ D_{2} = 4 < |z| < 8 \\ D_{3} = |z| > 8 $$

But **I'm not sure if I should use a Laurent or a Taylor series.** Since D1 deals with negative infinity, maybe a Laurent is needed there.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: typo, thanks for noticing. :)

Comment: If you take the partial fractions decomposition of $f(z)$, you should then be able to find the Laurent series in the regions.

Comment: The function has only 2 poles! So why do you have a problem with finding the domain of $f(z) $?

Answer (score 1):

We can decompose $f(z)$ as 
$$
f(z) = \frac{1-2i}{20(z-4)} - \frac{1-2i}{20(z+8i)}
$$
For the first region, $\lvert z\rvert < 4\Rightarrow \frac{\lvert z\rvert}{4}<1$. Since $\frac{\lvert z\rvert}{4}<1$, $\frac{\lvert z\rvert}{8}<\frac{1}{2}<1$
\begin{align}
\frac{1-2i}{20(z-4)} - \frac{1-2i}{20(z+8i)} 
&= \frac{1-2i}{-80}\frac{1}{1-\frac{\lvert z\rvert}{4}}-\frac{1-2i}{160i}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\lvert z\rvert}{8i}}\\
&= \frac{2i-1}{80}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{z}{4}\Bigr)^n+\frac{2+i}{160}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}i^n\Big(\frac{z}{8}\Bigr)^n\tag{1}
\end{align}
Additionally, you can simplify $(1)$ however you see fit. You then would do the same analysis for the second and third regions.